# How to write a function in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

A Pig newbie here. I have a relation `A` with multiple fields (`f1`,`f2`...). I want to quickly see all the distinct values that are there in each field.

Right now, I am doing this:

```
f1 = FOREACH A GENERATE f1;
f1 = DISTINCT f1;
dump f1;
```

I don't want to do this for each field. It is too elaborate. Is it possible instead to write some kind of a function in Pig to do this. I've looked at UDFs in the documentation, but I don't want to switch to another language like Java or Python. I think Pig is fine for what I am doing.

Comment: `"I want to quickly see all the distinct values that are there in each field."` ... `"I don't want to do this for each field."`  So you *do* and *don't* want to see the distinct of each field? that's a tall task.

Comment: @GoBrewers14 Sorry, I am not a native English speaker. If you understood what I meant, please feel free to edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is a **Macro**. This is the equivalent to a function.

```
DEFINE MY_MACRO(relation,field) RETURNS selected_field_distinct {
    selected_field = FOREACH $relation GENERATE $field;
    $selected_field_distinct = DISTINCT selected_field;
};


A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1:chararray, f2:chararray);

F1 = MY_MACRO(A,'f1');
F2 = MY_MACRO(A,'f2');

DUMP F1
DUMP F2
```

Please note that:

- You have to declare the macro above the location where you use it.
- You can also write your macro on a different file and import it to your script.
- There is no way to use the command **DUMP** within the macro [as described here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-3910).

Answer (score 1):

A thought worth contemplating ....

If the values seen in f1 will not occur in f2 then you can try this approach. In this case we are performing DISTINCT only once.

```
   f1  = FOREACH A GENERATE f1;
   f2  = FOREACH A GENERATE f2;
   ...
   f10 = FOREACH A GENERATE f10;

   all_values = UNION f1,f2,..., f10;

   uniq_values = DISTINCT all_values;
   DUMP uniq_values;
```

Comment: I was looking for a more generic solution and using macros would be the best in that case. But Thanks, I got to know about using "DISTINCT" on a relation because of your answer.